# Knockout foreach wrap by 4

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Have an existing array, and i want it display by 4 in a group wrapped by div:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: roomCards">
     <!-- ko if: ($index == 0 || ($index + 1) % 4) -->
     <div class="swiper-slide">
     <!-- /ko -->
     <div>
        data
     <div>
     <!-- ko if: ($index == 0 || ($index + 1) % 4) -->
     </div>
     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Ko if doesn't work because it only opens tag (breaking DOM)
But that doesn't work.

Need something like this:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
        <div>
           data
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Give the ViewModel a corresponding level of grouping:

```
self.roomCards = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);

self.roomCardsGrouped = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.roomCards().chunk(4);
});
```

The mentioned `chunk` method is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/419956) (credit to @ninjagecko), an excerpt:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function(chunkSize) {
    var array=this;
    return [].concat.apply([],
        array.map(function(elem,i) {
            return i%chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i,i+chunkSize)];
        })
    );
}
```

At any rate, update your view to something like this:

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: roomCardsGrouped">
     <div class="swiper-slide">
         <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
         <div>
             <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
         </div>
         <!-- /ko -->
     </div>
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czu5D/) for a demo.

Comment: I like this method overall, but I'm not a huge fan of modifying the Array prototype. Stick that `chunk` method on your view model or on a new global namespace instead. I do believe using the computed observable is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap `$index` like so `$index()`, also the data `div` has 2 opening tags rather than one closing tag:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: roomCards">
     <!-- ko if: ($index() == 0 || ($index() + 1) % 4) -->
     <div class="swiper-slide">
     <!-- /ko -->
     <div>
        data
     </div> 
     <!-- ko if: ($index() == 0 || ($index() + 1) % 4) -->
     </div>
     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Part of the problem here is that there is no closing tag after `<div>data` Instead there is a new opening tag.

Comment: thanks @crush, didn't spot that. Have updated the answer

Comment: I didn't spot it either until I put your code into a jsfiddle. I think that is probably part of the reason the OP was stuck.

Comment: @crush indeed, if you share the fiddle link I'll include it

Comment: jsfiddle is erroring out for me now (site problem, not code)...not sure what happened.